# With Nested_attributes dispaying model using ID catched in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to list Author Name from Author model while showing Books model.  I'm uncertain the syntax to grab the column from Authors model using the saved Author_ID in the Books model.

My Schema for both models:

```
CREATE TABLE "authors" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE "books" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "title" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL, "author_id" integer);
```

The index.html.erb for books:

```
<h1>Listing books</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= book.title %></td>
    <td><%= book.author_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', book %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(book) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', book, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Book', new_book_path %>
```

The current output

```
    Listing books

Title                                   Author          
Dirty Dozen                             2      Show    Edit    Destroy
Life and Times of Rich and Famous       1      Show    Edit    Destroy
Digby Manual                            4      Show    Edit    Destroy
Piano for Pros                          5      Show    Edit    Destroy
Pints and Pubs                          6      Show    Edit    Destroy
```

I want to use something to the effect of `<td><%= author.(book.author_id).name %></td>` to get the Author's name using the author's ID.

Answer (score 0):

in the Book model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  ...
```

in the Author model:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  ...
```

in the controller index action (to avoid n+1 queries)

```
@books = Book.includes(:author).all # or your criteria
```

And finally

```
<td><%= book.author.name %></td>
```

Comment: Getting undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass